# Как отправить данные через ajax по двойному клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно передать `id` через `ajax` после двойного клика на кнопку `.delete_button` как это правильно сделать ?

```
$(".delete_button").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cache: false,
            success: function(html) {    
            $("#output1").html( html );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть функция jQuery  **dblclick()** вот простой пример использования функции:

```js
$('#bloc').dblclick(function() {
  $('#bloc').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
  #bloc {
    background: #20B10F;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #bloc.active {
    background: #EE5847;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bloc"></div>
<span>Двойной клик</span>
```

Comment: `dblclick` это функция jQuery а не "_стандартная функция js_".

Comment: Спасибо исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Кстати, если клик нормально трагслируется в тач (тэп) на телефоне, то dblclick на телефоне по умолчанию не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `$.dblclick` вместо `$.click`:

```
$(".delete_button").dblclick(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#output1").html( html );
        }
    });
});
```